# visual studio 2015 publish web only have custom option

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2015, web-publishing

I am using visual studio 2015 to do the web publish of web project. But it seems that several options in web publish profile are missing. There should be include the options in this link [Publishing to IIS with Web Deploy using Visual Studio 2015](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy.html). 
I have tried to repair the installation, also try to use the vs under the different user. But not worked.
Below is the screenshot of my profile page of the web publish.
[Publish web profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJOlJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.
Just reinstall the web publish plugin by using the visual studio command prompt. The dll is under your installation disk. And 14.0 is for visual studio 2015.

```
gacutil -i "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.dll"
```