# VS 2015: Cannot see all options for publish under "Select a publish target"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-deployment

I cannot see option for **importing publish profile**, while web deploy. Only 'CUSTOM' option shown. I updated VS2015 Community Edition 2015 to Update2. It did not solve the problem. I Uninstall Visual Studio and Installed it again including update2 . But still facing same issue. 
This ticket also did not work: [visual studio 2015 publish web only have custom option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700361/visual-studio-2015-publish-web-only-have-custom-option)

[image]

I am missing something or something else? Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Azure SDK 2.9(or latest one) solved the problem.